# Make 'R' and 'B' Elements in an 2D RGB Array zero in Python

Tags: python, arrays, rgb

I trying to make values in an 2D RGB array zero.  For this case, I want the Red and Blue elements in the array to be zero.  I have tried this where `rgb_img` is the RGB image array:

```
r = rgb_img[:, :, 0]
g = rgb_img[:, :, 1]
b = rgb_img[:, :, 2]
mask = (r < 200) & (g < 200) & (b < 200)
rgb_img[mask] = 0
bg = rgb_img
print bg
```

However, the output I get is not what I expect:

```
 [[   0.   255.     0.5]
  [   0.   255.     0.5]
  [   0.   255.     0.5]
  ..., 
  [   0.   255.     0.5]
  [   0.5  255.     0. ]
  [   0.   255.     0.5]]
```

But what I am looking for is this:

```
 [[   0.   255.     0.]
  [   0.   255.     0.]
  [   0.   255.     0.]
  ...,
  [   0.   255.     0.]
  [   0.   255.     0.]
  [   0.   255.     0.]]
```

Comment: `&` is `bitwise` operator , do you mean that our you mean `or`?

Comment: I used `&` because when I'm applying it to the array, the `bit-wise and` is applied element-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, it was as simple as:

```
rgb_img[:, :, 0] = 0
rgb_img[:, :, 2] = 0
```